# Log files that hold in court as evidences

Tags: logging

does anyone knows a web service that provide logging facilities so that the log files hold in court as evidences?

In particular, I'm searching for some kind of web service - at best accessible via a RESTful interface - that I can use to write my logging entries in a non-modifiable database of a trusted third party. In case of a court process, this trusted third party should be able to export a reliable log file for my system.

Or are there any mechanisms/techniques/frameworks that help me in creating non-modifiable log files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, logging anything without knowledge and consent is not going to hold up in court. If you obtain a subpaena or court order to do something like that, then they'd probably have a team to help you out.